# How can I manage Virt-Manager from a windows machine without X11 Forwarding?

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualization, xorg, linux-kvm

I am currently in the middle of a project, and have a machine with CentOS 7 and KVM as my virtualization server. 
Sadly enough, I have to find a way to manage my guests from a Windows 10 machine, and until now, I've been using X11 Forwarding with VcXsrv and PuTTY, but the graphic interface is laggy, and there's just no way to keep the system like this.
 So basically, what I need is to run virt-manager on windows and after long researching, the only thing I found was [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/340949/is-there-a-way-to-run-virt-manager-on-windows?newreg=5f6e5abb77704fec97b67e1c07ae4520) and the most interesting comment by [AndreasT](https://serverfault.com/a/451479/379790), suggesting CygWin. I do have cygwin installed, and windows 10 bash on ubuntu on windows, but trying to run virt-manager with debug on WSL throws a lot of errors in packages (even having them installed), and i couldn't find anywhere how to use virt-manager on CygWin.
The idea is to set the manager on Windows, and connect via SSH to the CentOS machine, to manage the guests on KVM.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered running XVnc and virt-manager on the servers, then connect via VNC from whatever you need (Windows, Mac, Android, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some more research and trying, I actually found what was wrong in my windows-KVM setup. First of all, I had to export my $DISPLAY, after installing XMing on windows 10 (Still required to work), then I had to fix a Dbus error, following [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4rsmzp/bash_on_windows_getting_dbus_and_x_server_working/). This was the key to solving my problems, as it made possible for me to initialize my virt-manager on windows. I am posting more useful threads that helped me solving the problem:

- [Spice client gtk error](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224776)
- [Dbus Daemon error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354967/glib-gerror-no-d-bus-daemon-running)
- [Using VNC instead of Spice protocol](https://serverfault.com/questions/686895/kvm-virt-manager-stuck-in-password-prompt-after-open-vm)

Also thanks to [Eugen Rieck](https://superuser.com/users/300968/eugen-rieck) for the insight on the VNC.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative provide cygwin with x11 that can be installed with virt-manager and ran out from windows [cygwin virt-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAPQ3.png)

Comment: I added a "HowTo" do this on this answer >> https://serverfault.com/questions/340949/is-there-a-way-to-run-virt-manager-on-windows